# Ruby on Rails bootstrap alert box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notifications, alert, bootstrap-4

In my application I show messages to users like this way.

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= key %> alert-dismissible">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <%= value %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I have following lines in my application

```
.alert-notice {
  @extend .alert-warning;
}
```

When I redirect user with redirect_to root_url, :notice => 'messages' everything perfect. Notice message can be seen. However when I direct user with redirect_to root_url, :info => 'messages', No message can be seen. I have debugged code and realised that flash is empty that condition.

It's ok:

```
redirect_to root_url, :notice => 'messages'
```

Here is problem:

```
redirect_to root_url, :info => 'messages'
```

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `info` you have to add this to `application_helper.rb`

```
add_flash_types :info
```

You can add as many extra types as you want, e.g.

```
add_flash_types :info, :success, :warning, :danger
```

*Extra:*

I would also suggest you get used to the new hast notation in Ruby

```
redirect_to root_url, info: 'messages' # instead of :info => ...
```

Comment: I didn't know about `add_flash_types`, nice.

Answer (score 0):

`:info` is not a vaild option for `redirect` (only `:alert` and `:notice` can be used that way); so, to use `info`, you must assign it directly to `flash`.

Try this instead:

```
flash[:info] = 'messages'
redirect_to root_url
```

Or this:

```
redirect_to root_url, flash: { info: 'messages' }
```

Comment: Dear downvoter, i will  appreciate any insight on the shortcomings of my answer so i have the opportunity to make it better.